# Fetch API gives me undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

I´m new to nodejs and API, but I'm trying to display data from the API to the browser but it shows up as undefined. When I inspect the page the data is there under networks. How can i fix this?

my router:

```
array=[];
Router.get('/products', (req, res) => {
    res.send(array);
});

//get one product
Router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
    mysqlConnection.query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = ?", [req.params.id], (err, rows, fields) => {
        if(!err){
           
          array.push(rows);
          res.send(rows);
          
        }  else{
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Where is the fetch?

Comment: You have a array in an array. you do not appear to be referencing an array in an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code rows is an array. You push an array to an array. You you have a 2D array. You want to push the items to the array so it is 1D

```
dataid.push(...rows);
res.send(rows);
```

Answer (score -1):

Your router has */productsIDD* path but your are requesting for */products/productsIDD*

Please write a new path for */products/productsIDD* or rewrite the exiting path (*/productsIDD*) to */products/productsIDD*